# What is best Solution architecture

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have 3 Physical servers. and i want to utilise for SharePoint 2016 , i want to utilise in best possible way

- Server 1 - 8 lCPU, 8GB RAM
- Server 2 - 4 lCPU, 16GB RAM
- Server 3 - 8 lCPU, 32GB RAM

Comment: How much data/traffic/users/applications have you got? Do you need to serve little data very fast? Or should you focus on HA and redundancy?

Comment: i am want to host one public facing SharePoint site , i want to configure in Best Possibly way using HA

Answer (score 0):

3 servers that asymmetrical: no the best case to start with.
Anyway, I would definitely use Server 3 (32GB RAM) to host the SQL database: SQL Server will most benefit a high memory by loading/caching data.
(note: there's no HA for SQL Server here...)

If the expected number of users/requests is not too high (let's say less than 1000 users and/or less than 30 requests par minute), Server 2 (16 GB) may handle the load by itself. This way, you cant keep Server 1 for handover if Server 2 fails.
Server 1 would still be part of the initial farm, completely up and running, but would not necessarily be part of the load-balancing if you can't afford actual load-balancing. Failover would occur manually, e.g. by changing DNS configuration.

In all cases, this is far from ideal.